# SQL Reporting Services Express Edition very slow even with no data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Am trying to figure out why our SSRS execution is so slow.  The home page takes about 10 seconds to load/refresh and reports take 12-15 seconds just to render to the 'Enter Parameter Settings' stage.

I have created a report with a single text box - no data connections - no data-set - so ZERO database access and yet it still consistently takes 12 seconds to render - A SINGLE TEXT BOX WITH NO DATABASE ACCESS!  Every single click in the report engine takes 12-15 seconds to respond to - which makes it quite painful to work with real data.

The database and an IIS installation is also included on the same machine - but they are only accessed by a couple of users (nothing public) - so the machine isn't under a lot of load.  All other services on this box are responding quickly: The IIS installation is serving up web-service requests quickly and responsively - within a split-second.  And all database queries are running at a very speedy rate - consistent with the generous hardware on this box.

It doesn't seem to be related to 'First Request' spooling up - this is happening on all requests.

All the other answers relating to SSRS speed issues seem to be related to database query tuning and parameter handling - but this 'no-data' test report seems to be pointing to something wrong within the SSRS installation/execution itself.

Any help?

Comment: Have you checked the `dbo.ExecutionLog2` view in the ReportServer db? What are the rendering stat times showing, are they consistent with the 12-15 seconds you're experiencing? If not, then it could point to something other than SSRS issues.

Comment: You are right - the dbo.ExecutionLog2 shows the execution times are nice and quick - so there is something else going on...   I have now discovered when I open/execute a report from the ReportServer (eg: http://myurl/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?Product+Sales&rs:Command=Render) rather than the SSRS interface (eg: http://myurl/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=Product+Sales) then I get super quick (ie: normal) execution.  So what could be up with the SSRS interface that would cause it to take up to 15 seconds before it executes a report?

Comment: I have discovered a sort of fix: When I open/execute a report from the ReportServer (eg: http://[mylocalurl]/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?Product+Sales&rs:Command=Render) I get normal (fast) execution time. But when I open them from the SSRS interface (eg: http://[mylocalurl]/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=Product+Sales) then I get the 10-15 second delay before the report is rendered. So what could be up with the SSRS interface that would cause it to take up to 15 seconds before it executes a report?

Comment: Sql 2008 onward doesn't require IIS for serving up reports via SSRS interface, and I don't know enough about IIS to comment on any interactions that may or may not be happening, but it could be something simpole like assigning a different port number for SSRS, i.e. if IIS is listening on port 80, then have SSRS configured to listen on 8080 was a suggestion for dealing with IIS issues in 2005 SSRS, perhaps it could help here? [Here's some info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447(v=sql.100).aspx) that may be of use.

Answer (score 2):

I would run Report Manager locally from the server and have Task Manager up to monitor the activity of the server to identify possible server resource issues and rule out network/client connectivity issues.

Even though you are using a "dummy" report with no DataSource, IIS still has to talk to SQL Server to get report metadata.  I would check to make sure all the SSRS components are talking to each other by using the [Reporting Services Configuration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156305%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for your specific SQL version.